# Switch div background every x clicks on same div

Tags: jquery, click

I need to count clicks on a div to switch its background every 10 clicks.
Like click, click, click... load background#1... click, click, click... load background#2, and so on.
I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this with jQuery.

What i have now is a basic show on click event.

```
$('#div1').click(function() {
  $('#div1-bg').show();
});
```

Do not know how to add the counter.

Comment: Yes, there is .

Comment: please provide what you've tried and if not then check out w3schools and over StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the simplest way to do this...

```
var backgrounds = ['https://i.imgur.com/0v2hGkA.gif', 'https://i.imgur.com/wPVNqt4.gif'];
var clickCount = 10;
var clicks = 0;
var backgroundPosition = 0;

$('#div1').on('click', function(){
    clicks++;
    if (clicks % clickCount === 0){
        backgroundPosition = ++backgroundPosition >= backgrounds.length ? 0 : backgroundPosition;
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + backgrounds[backgroundPosition] + ')');
    }   
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi joero4, this definitely helps! Thank you very much.